# Can't Reference the Owner in the Process Builder but can in workflow

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, reference

I am trying to reference the Owner in process builder and cannot.  However, it works in workflow.  I'm trying to use all of the new features for all of my development so obviously the simple answer is "use workflow"

However, my question is:  How can I get the Owner First Name and Last Name references in process builder?

Edit:  my owner id will not traverse further for my custom object

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a standard object you need to traverse through the lookups in the field selector to get to the user object and then fist name.

The lookup fields are the one with a > next to it. So if this was an Account you would find Owner ID > Click that and then select First name.

[image]

If this is a custom object it looks like currently in Summer '16 you cannot reference the owner like you can in standard objects. The next best solution is to create formula fields that pull in the First name and last name and use that custom field(s) in your process.

Comment: for my custom object I don't have anything past owner id

Comment: ah yeah looks like it's not there for custom objects only standard objects. Aside from using APEX to do the update I think your next option would be to make a formula field and then use that in the reference.

Comment: Maybe change your answer to what you just commented and I can mark that is correct.